# Recovering pictures from Internal storgae

Tags: internal-storage

We have an Android Verizon Ellipsis Tablet QMV7A.  We deleted our pictures and videos but desperately want them back.  They were not on an mini SD card, but on the tablet's internal memory.  When we connect the tablet to a PC is shows up as QMV7A and has a folder under that labeled "Internal Storage" with subfolders "DCIM, Videos, etc."  So the PC sees the internal storage, but no recovery software I have recognizes the internal storage.  How to I scan and recover files from the internal storage when I can't get programs like Card Recovery or others to recognize it?   Running Android 4.2.2 Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Android Data Recovery can recover your deleted/formatted files from Android devices without taking out the SD card or CF card inside the Android phone or tablet. This program has a strong ability that not only can recover photos and videos, but also can recover contacts, text messages, and other data. You can download it from the play store. 
I'm not sure if you've used backup photo apps but generally speaking Google photos automatically backup your photos. Try sending a text message and adding a photo as an attachment  it'll bring up a menu and it might show the places that your photos are saved to, you can also try downloading a file manager like ES and look for them there. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Russlee.  I have tried that software and it does not seem to want to recover from the Internal Storage.  Only the SD card.  The internal storgae was were the tablet was saving the pictures.